# html5 non-stopping video background loop even if network speed/buffer is low

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, buffer

I am using some nice html5 video background for div, but on very slow connections, it is pausing for buffering every second. 
I want to create such logic: start playing after 10s buffered, and if playback is faster and it start buffering, *smoothly* seek video to begin (or to buffered range), to allow more buffering and don't stop playback (position doesn't matter much).

So the goal is have a forever-playing looping video, even if buffer is low

I found some code in this question: [How to detect whether HTML5 video has paused for buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399872/how-to-detect-whether-html5-video-has-paused-for-buffering)

And tried it in such way:

```
var checkInterval  = 50.0
var lastPlayPos    = 0
var currentPlayPos = 0
var bufferingDetected = false

setInterval(checkBuffering, checkInterval)

function checkBuffering() {
    var player = document.getElementById('bgvideo')
    currentPlayPos = player.currentTime

    // checking offset, e.g. 1 / 50ms = 0.02
    var offset = 1 / checkInterval

    // if no buffering is currently detected,
    // and the position does not seem to increase
    // and the player isn't manually paused...
    if (
            !bufferingDetected 
            && currentPlayPos < (lastPlayPos + offset)
            && !player.paused
        ) {
        console.log("buffering")
        bufferingDetected = true
        player.currentTime=0; //seek to begin
    }

    // if we were buffering but the player has advanced,
    // then there is no buffering
    if (
        bufferingDetected 
        && currentPlayPos > (lastPlayPos + offset)
        && !player.paused
        ) {
        console.log("not buffering anymore")
        bufferingDetected = false
    }
    lastPlayPos = currentPlayPos
}
```

It doesn't work well, because when seeking to begin, buffer is flushed sometimes and it start buffering from begin. The seeking is not smooth and give a 2 sec pause, also this code don't resolve 10s prebuffer on beginning.

I've heared about  MSE, but I am not sure it is supported everywhere and is very hard to understand.

Experts, please help!

Comment: depending on the size of your video you may be able to use this technique - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18251632/another-force-chrome-to-fully-buffer-mp4-video/18294706#18294706 - to fully load the video and play it back from a local buffer rather than stream...

Comment: That's not an option, I need to have instant playback. But thanks for answer

Comment: a multi-bitrate format (ie HLS) will help get you started quickly and can step up/down quality as bitrate improves, but to get what you want you'll probably need a very low quality option in the stream.

Comment: I know about DASH. but not all browsers support it. Can I use DASH with fallback, like keep <source> in <video> tag?